# Online drills for Keller and Russell's Learn to Read Latin?

Tags: resource-request, pedagogy

I'm currently teaching with Keller and Russell's *Learn to Read Latin*. I have a vague memory that there exists, or used to exist, a website with drills and exercises that are specifically keyed to the chapters of that textbook, but if so, I can't seem to find it again. (My students are doing the drills in the workbook but it would be useful to them to have online drills as well.) Does anyone know if such a site exists and where it can be found?

Comment: I don't know but I've corresponded with Keller about their *Learn to Read Greek* and he's fairly quick to reply. You might write him and ask.

Comment: If anyone writes the authors and asks, please post the result here if it is not too confidential. We want the solution here, not just in a couple inboxes. (@JoelDerfner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is the site you are remembering?

http://www.teach-and-learn-latin.org/learn-to-read-latin.html

It has a lot of "noise," but it has interactive games for the different chapters.